# Binary operation 100 * 2 << 20

Tags: binary, binary-operators

I'm trying to find an explanation for the left operand operation.
How much is it in decimal: **100 * 2 << 20** ?

Comment: x << y == x * 2 ^ y ... as long as there is no overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like that : `a << b` means `a * 2 ^ b`